# show data from multiple table order by datetime

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

I have a php page and want to display data from multiple tables (currently 3 tables)
all tables have date-time column
and other columns are totally different (in numbers & data-type etc)
I want to display
most recent row from either of three tables
2nd most recent row from either of three tables
3rd most recent row from either of three tables
and so on

my tables structure is like below

```
ATTANDANCE [a_id,date-time,employee,attandance_more....]   

TASKS_ASSIGN[ta_id,date-time,employee,title,detail,duration,task_assign_more.....]

TASK_COMPLETED [tc_id,date-time,employee,stars,task_completed_more....]
```

i want to display as facebook as

```
 Alam has joined office at 23-mar-2013 **08:00am**   
 Haider has joined office at 23-mar-2013 **08:01am**  
 Alam has completed xyz-task at 22-mar-2013 **03:45pm**
 Alam has joined office at 22-mar-2013 **10:12am**
 ......
```

Comment: Since your columns are totally different, I don't think this is possible with one request in SQL. You will have to sort the entries in PHP.

Comment: yes I am totally agree with u
but how can I sort in php

as much I know

  select * from attandance where (my conditions) order by date-time desc
   keep in $row1
   
   select * from tasks_assigned where (my conditions) order by date-time desc
   keep in $row2

   select * from tasks_completed where (my conditions) order by date-time desc
   keep in  $row3

   some how merge it in an array(this is what I don't know)
   sort the array
   Didplay sorted records (but how will I know current row belongs to which table)

please help
or
any alternative

Comment: I typed above comment in notepad and here newlines are removed.....    Shortly I want to know how can we merge different resultsets and sort them in php?

Comment: you add all the resultsets to one array then you use the function usort. For that you will need to write a "compare" function based on the date-time. See the PHP doc on usort for more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you add all the results (from the 3 tables) in one array.($theArray)
Then you sort the array using [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php). Something like this :

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if ($a->date-time == $b->date-time) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a->date-time < $b->date-time) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($theArray, "cmp");
```

Comment: I tried this....1-setched data from database........3-assigned it to array.......4-applied usort as u mantioned above......it rarranges the records but not in corrent order...... I tried making array assigning same values(manually) as fetched from DB.......then sorted it, that returns in correct order......then I replaced a line in your above function........return(date("d-M-Y H:i A",strtotime($a['date-time'])) >date("d-M-Y H:i A",strtotime($b['date-time'])) >)?-1:1;..........but still not sorting

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you only want a subset of the columns.  I'm not sure what the exact relationship is between the tables and your results, but something like:

```
select  'attandance' as which, employee, `datetime`
from attendance
union all
select 'assign' as which, employee, `datetime`
from tasks_assign
union all
select `completed` as which, employee, `datetime`
from tasks_completed
order by `datetime` desc
```

That is, you can use subqueries to get just a subset of the columns in each table.  Then use `union all` to bring them together and `order by` to put them in the order you want.

Comment: well you could do something like this but it will soon get really complicated. "Alam has completed xyz-task at 22-mar-2013 **03:45pm**". You want also the task_name, and probably many other fields

Comment: will that work for different number of columns and different data-types?   and I will display them differently